# How to access or assign a UIButton tag if the corresponding button is an element of an NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nsarray

I am currently implementing a simple card game for iOS. I did the following to set the button tag of the UIButton firstCardButton:

```
self.firstCardButton.tag = 1;
```

Now, I need twenty buttons instead of one. Therefore, I am using an array containing all buttons like:

```
self.buttonArray=@[self.firstCardButton,self.secondCardButton, ... ];
```

I think I will improve this later on. But now the question I'd like to ask:

Is it possible to assign the tag to an element of the array? I tried the following without success:

```
[self.buttonArray objectAtIndex:0].tag = 1;
```

My actual version does simply:

```
self.firstCardButton.tag = 1;
self.secondCardButton.tag = 2;
self.thirdCardButton.tag = 3;
self.fourthCardButton.tag = 4;
...
```

Has anyone an idea how to write this in a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're doing something manually in a sequential order, there will pretty much always be a better way, and that way will almost always be a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop to iterate your `NSArray`, and assign the tags, like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != buttonArray.count ; i++) {
    [[buttonArray objectAtIndex:i] setTag:i+1];
}
```

Note: I am assuming that the buttons are not created through UI Builder, because otherwise you would have an opportunity to set their tags by configuring them inside your storyboard / NIB file.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. It seems to work fine =)

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != array.count ; i++) {
UIButton *but=(UIbutton *)[array objectAtIndex:i];
butt.tag=i;

}
```